# How to use MVVMCross in a Blank Android App

Tags: android, xamarin, configuration, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

How do I implemement MVVMCross in a "[Blank Android App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nupqF.png)" 
Is it possible to do this without a Portable Class Library (PCL)?

Do I have to create an App.cs class (The project doesn't come with one included) and is that even possible?

If I do have to then how do I do it?

Comment: have you tried reading the docs?  https://mvvmcross.com/docs/getting-started

Comment: @Jason, I have tried reading the docs but they are for a xamarin app that has a PCL, im wanting to use MVVMCross without a PCL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research I found that you can create an App.cs file (ie a class that extends the `Android.App.Application` class) in a 'Blank Android App' and hence don't need a PCL to use MVVMCross.

You must ensure that you have an implementation of the `public App(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)` constructor and some people state that you also need to override the OnCreate method (as i have done).

Also make sure that in your AssemblyInfo.cs file you DONT have a any [Application] lines ie. None of this: `[assembly: Application(Debuggable = true)]`

See code below.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using System;

namespace YOUR.NAMESPACE
{
#if DEBUG
    [Application(Debuggable = true)]
#else
    [Application(Debuggable = false)]
#endif
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
            //Do MVVMCross setup Here
            //Mvx.RegisterType<ICalculation,Calculation>();
            //Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxAppStart>(new MvxAppStart<TipViewModel>());
        }
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A good example for startes is the TipCalc-Tutorial which you will find on the official github page (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki), just be careful since most tutorials are for 4.0 so there might some changes. As a example:

> When asked to choose platforms, select .NET Framework 4.5, Windows 8,
>   Windows Phone Silverlight 8, Windows Phone 8.1, Xamarin.Android and
>   Xamarin.iOS - this will ensure that the PCL is in Profile259.

Is outdated since Silverlight isnt supported anymore from MVVMCross 4.2.2 onwards. So you should use Profile 7 as a Example. More informations for PCL Profiles here: http://danrigby.com/2014/05/14/supported-pcl-profiles-xamarin-for-visual-studio-2/

But yeah you basically should have a Portable Class Library, even if it would work without it. It just gives many advantages without requiring much effort.

And you dont need a "App.cs", but you need a class which inherits from MvxApplication. So it might be easier to stick with that name, since everyone knows then what it is for.

But just check out the tutorials first, everything in there should be explained.

Comment: Hey @Cyriac Thanks for the links to the tutorials they are really good however you can actually use MVVMCross without a PCL, See answer.

Comment: Yeah guessed that it might work, but still not a huge fan to miss out the advantages without it. But probably a choice depending on the project. But good to know that it works for sure!

Comment: Yeah it was a project requirement